# Command for formatting a special term

Tags: macros, formatting

How can write a new command which formats a certain 2-word-term always in a special font, all uppercase, with the line-height of the uppercase characters being the same as the line-height of down-case characters in normal text??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sounds like a job for small caps. It prints all lower case letters as small upper case letters. You can use `\MakeLowercase` to ensure all letters are lower case.

```
\documentclass{article}

%\newcommand{\term}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\newcommand{\term}[1]{\MakeLowercase{\textsc{#1}}}

\begin{document}

Text \term{Two Words} text

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]